# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

Примеренная connect в  проинициализирована в  include 'conf.php';
Помогите найти и исправит ошибку:

> `Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in U:\home\project\www\core.php on line 12`

core.php:

```
    <?php
   include 'conf.php';

      class Addpostdb{
       var $name;
       var $text;

      function add($name,$text){
       $query="INSERT INTO posts 
            VALUES ( '$name','$text')";
        if (mysql_query($query, $connect) or die("error:" . mysql_error())){
            echo 'Выполнено';
                                                                           }

                               }
                      }
   class Viewpost{
       function view(){
           $result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `posts`');
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ echo $row['name']. '<p>'.$row['post'];
}
       } 
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы передаёте в функцию mysql_query вторым параметром переменную $connection, которая нигде не проинициализирована.

Answer (score 0):

Если переменная инициализирована в conf.php, тогда надо сделать так:

```
  ...
  function add($name,$text){
     global $connect;
     $query="INSERT INTO posts.....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$connect
```

просто убери ее, вряд ли у тебя там 10 соединений...

и еще

**ВСЕ КТО ЧИТАЕТ ЭТОТ ПОСТ,** **ВНИМАНИЕ!!!**

Никогда не пишите код классами так, как это делает ТС, это и без классов говнокод ужасный! смысл то от того что ты написал классами??? я в шоке...возьми учебник по php и прочитай! а потом говорят что язык плохой, тут таким как ТС надо руки из одного места достать, бедный пых...что он терпит...